# SP: Random Records, Fave Record, Plus Known Record, NO repetition

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Thanks to help from a lot of you guys ive been given the following code which works great. However ive realised ive missed an important bit of info out of the question and so have reposted here (with updated code) to clarify.

The following code gets 5 random records from a table plus a further single record based on the users favourite as identified in a second table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE web.getRandomCharities
   (
   @tmp_ID bigint --members ID
   )
AS
BEGIN

    WITH    q AS
     (
     SELECT  TOP 5 *
     FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
     WHERE   cha_Active = 'TRUE'
             AND cha_Key != '1'
     ORDER BY NEWID()
     )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    (
     SELECT  *
     FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
     WHERE   TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key IN
             (
             SELECT  members_Favourite
             FROM    TBL_MEMBERS
             WHERE   members_Id = @tmp_ID
             )
     EXCEPT
     SELECT  *
     FROM    q
     ) tc

END
```

However, i realised i also need to include the record where "cha_Key == '1'" if it isnt the same as the record returned in the second SELECT statement in the code shown above.

HOpe that makes sense?

THANKS!!!

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and a resultset you'd like to get?

Comment: It is preferred that you just edit your original question with more details. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7771/is-this-abuse-or-misunderstanding-of-the-way-things-work

Comment: Quassnoi,

Ok so what i want to do is everything as above, but also get the record that weve eliminated in the first statement (cha_Key != '1'
) if it isnt the users favourite(as return by the union statement)

Essentially i want 5 unique random records(but not record No1), plus the users favourite record, plus record No1 if its not the favourite.

Record No1 should always come out as the 1st record.

Hope this explaines better?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand you but I believe it goes something like this...

Five random records without #1
One User specific record
Record #1 if it's NOT user's specific record.

If so, I believe this does that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE web.getRandomCharities
   (
   @tmp_ID bigint --members ID
   )
AS
BEGIN
    WITH    q AS
     (
     SELECT  TOP 5 *
     FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
     WHERE   cha_Active = 'TRUE'
             AND cha_Key != '1'
     ORDER BY NEWID()
     )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    (
     SELECT  *
     FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
     WHERE   TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key IN
             (
             SELECT  members_Favourite
             FROM    TBL_MEMBERS
             WHERE   members_Id = @tmp_ID
             )
     EXCEPT
     SELECT  *
     FROM    q
     ) tc
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    (
     SELECT  *
     FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
     WHERE   TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key NOT IN
             (
             SELECT  members_Favourite
             FROM    TBL_MEMBERS
             WHERE   members_Id = @tmp_ID
             )
        AND (TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key = '1')
     EXCEPT
     SELECT  *
     FROM    q
     ) tc
END
```